# cakephp div and button toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp

Need to solve CakePHP and Script problem

I am using three buttons(**let b1,b2 & b3**). Three buttons have its own separate div (**let d1,d2 & d3**)respectively. when I click the **b1** ,then **d1** should display but other **d2 & d3 should hide**. When I click the **b2** then **d2** should display and **d3 and d1** should hide. How Should make this work using CakePHP and script in that?

Here is the code that I have tried

```
  <button id="b1"> btn1 </button>
  <button id="b2"> btn1 </button>
  <button id="b3"> btn1 </button>

  <div id="d1" style="display:none"> this is div1 </div>
  <div id="d2" style="display:none"> this is div2 </div>
  <div id="d3" style="display:none"> this is div2 </div>
```

// this is script

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(['block' => 'scriptBottom']); ?>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });


        $('#b1').click(function () {
         $('#d1').show();
         $('#d2').hide();
         $('#d3).hide();

        });


        $('#b2').click(function () {
         $('#d1').hide();
         $('#d2').show();
         $('#d3').hide();

        });

        $('#b3').click(function () {
         $('#d1').hide();
         $('#d2').hide();
         $('#d3').show();

        });
    }
    )( jQuery );

<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

Comment: show use your code, what did you  try?

Comment: Yes!. I have added. Can you help to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();//get the position of the current button 
      $('div').eq(index-1).show();// display the div corresponding to that position ,note: eq start counting from 0
      $('div').not(':eq('+(index-1)+')').hide();//hide the other usin not
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> btn1 </button>
  <button> btn1 </button>
  <button> btn1 </button>

  <div style="display:none"> this is div1 </div>
  <div style="display:none"> this is div2 </div>
  <div style="display:none"> this is div3 </div>
```

using ids:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var id = '#d_'+this.id.split('_')[1];
    console.log(id);
    $(id).show();
    $('div').not(id).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b_1"> btn1 </button>
<button id="b_2"> btn1 </button>
<button id="b_3"> btn1 </button>

<div id="d_1" style="display:none"> this is div1 </div>
<div id="d_2" style="display:none"> this is div2 </div>
<div id="d_3" style="display:none"> this is div3 </div>
```

Comment: Thank You : ) But What I need is when Click the button it will show the only its corresponding div. Other div should not be display.  In Your code everything is displaying right. :)

Comment: what do you mean by that, my code displays one filed for each button?

Comment: Oops! sorry my mistake. But why did you not using any **id** for divs and buttons. If I add more divs inside main div means, that will work?

Comment: yes it will work if you add multiple elements, note you need to add a class for the button/div to differentiate for the other elements in your page, you can do this with ids as well but you will need some string manipulation for that